# Ignore nan-values in guessdatetime-function, but raise ValueError when date-string cannot be converted

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm using a function to convert different string datetime formats to the same datetime format. I want the code to raise an error (ValueError) when there is a datetime format not between the options in list fmt, however I don't want it to raise an error (ValueError) when the input is empty (=NaN). I don't know what to add to the guess_date_function so that it doesn't raise a ValueError when the dataframe-cell is empty?

I tried to add str(np.nan) to the fmt-list but that returned 1900-01-01 for empty cells and I want to keep them empty (=NaN)

**Code**

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import datetime   

df = pd.DataFrame({"ID": [12,96,73,84,87,64,11,34], 
                 "Date": ['2016-01-01', '25Mar2019', '2018/01/01', '2017-01-01', '2013-01-01', '2016-01-01', '2019-01-01', '2014-01-01']}) 
print(df)  

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"ID": [12,96,20,73,84,26,87,64,11,34], 
                 "Date": ['2016-01-01', '25Mar2019', np.nan, '2018/01/01', '2017-01-01', np.nan, '2013-01-01', '2016-01-01', '2019-01-01', '2014-01-01']}) 
print(df2)  

def guess_date(string):
     for fmt in ["%Y/%m/%d", "%Y-%m-%d", "%d%m%Y", "%d%b%Y"]: 
        try: 
            return datetime.datetime.strptime(string, fmt).date() 
        except ValueError: 
            continue 
    raise ValueError(string)  

for i in range(len(df.Date)):  # len(result.DCP_lastmoddate) 
    df.loc[i, 'Date'] = guess_date(str(df.loc[i, 'Date'])) 
print(df.Date)   

for i in range(len(df2.Date)):  # len(result.DCP_lastmoddate) 
    df2.loc[i, 'Date'] = guess_date(str(df2.loc[i, 'Date'])) 
print(df2.Date)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

given the described setup, you could check for type `str`, which would return `False` for `np.nan`. I took the freedom to modify the function slightly so you can simply `apply` it:

```
def guess_date(string):
    if not isinstance(string, str):
        return pd.NaT
    for fmt in ["%Y/%m/%d", "%Y-%m-%d", "%d%m%Y", "%d%b%Y"]:
        try:
            return datetime.datetime.strptime(string, fmt).date()
        except ValueError:
            continue
    else:
        raise ValueError(f"incompatible string {string}")


df2['Date'].apply(guess_date)
# 0    2016-01-01
# 1    2019-03-25
# 2           NaT
# 3    2018-01-01
# 4    2017-01-01
# 5           NaT
# 6    2013-01-01
# 7    2016-01-01
# 8    2019-01-01
# 9    2014-01-01
# Name: Date, dtype: object
```

Note though that this is the same result you get from

```
pd.to_datetime(df2['Date']).dt.date
```

which is probably more efficient. So the function only serves the purpose to check for "undefined" formats.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. A check for date-formats that I didn't already cover and are present in a df-column.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest with you, I would try to refactor the code in the end. But here is the quick fix to ur code to accept nan values:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({"ID": [12,96,73,84,87,64,11,34],
                 "Date": ['2016-01-01', '25Mar2019', '2018/01/01', '2017-01-01', '2013-01-01', '2016-01-01', '2019-01-01', '2014-01-01']})
print(df)

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"ID": [12,96,20,73,84,26,87,64,11,34],
                 "Date": ['2016-01-01', '25Mar2019', np.nan, '2018/01/01', '2017-01-01', np.nan, '2013-01-01', '2016-01-01', '2019-01-01', '2014-01-01']})
print(df2)

def guess_date(string): 
   
   if pd.isnull(string):
       return(string)
   for fmt in ["%Y/%m/%d", "%Y-%m-%d", "%d%m%Y", "%d%b%Y"]:
        try:
            return datetime.datetime.strptime(string, fmt).date()
        except ValueError as e:
            continue
   raise ValueError(string)

for i in range(len(df.Date)):  # len(result.DCP_lastmoddate) 
    df.loc[i, 'Date'] = guess_date(df.loc[i, 'Date'])
print(df.Date)

for i in range(len(df2.Date)):  # len(result.DCP_lastmoddate) 
    df2.loc[i, 'Date'] = guess_date(df2.loc[i, 'Date'])
print(df2.Date)
```