# Time Parser will not operate-works well individually but all toget it does not

Tags: python, date, datetime

So I am trying to make a time parser to convert 1 of 3 times of time formats these into dd-mm-yy(28-sept-20.

all 3 work well individually but when they come together it does not work.

```
from datetime import datetime

def time_parser(self, time):
        try:
            start_period_obj = datetime.strptime(time, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
            print('variation 1 is what was used')
        except:
            start_period_obj = datetime.strptime(time, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
            print('variation 2 is what was used')
        else:
            start_period = time.split('T')[0]
            start_period_obj = datetime.strptime(time, "%Y-%m-%d")
            print('variation 3 is what was used')

        finally:
            start_period = time.split('T')[0]
            start_period_obj = datetime.strptime(time, "%Y-%m-%d")
            print('variation 4 is what was used')

        new_format = start_period_obj.strftime("%d-%b-%y")
        print('The start date is')
        print(new_format)
        return new_format

#the time formats
start_time1 = "2020-08-28T13:42:00.298363-05:00"
start_time2 = "2020-09-03T16:33:47.289147Z"
start_time3 = "2020-09-01T00:00:00-05:00"
start_time4 = "2020-09-03T16:33:47Z"



time_parser(start_time1)
```

and the output is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "time conveter.py", line 33, in <module>
    time_parser(start_time1)
TypeError: time_parser() missing 1 required positional argument: 'time'
```

The output I want is

```
dd-mm-yy
```

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you pass `self` to a function, this usually means it is a class method and *self* is the class instance. Here, this seems not to be the case. You get the error because you pass only one argument to the function - which is *self* and *time* is missing. If you want to use the function outside of a class, remove the self.

Furthermore, if you want to test different formats to parse a time string, better wrap them in a loop which runs in the try/except, e.g. as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64104970/10197418).

And finally, if those are all the time string formats you encounter, you can parse them nicely with `fromisoformat` ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat)):

```
from datetime import datetime

fmts = ("2020-08-28T13:42:00.298363-05:00",
        "2020-09-03T16:33:47.289147Z",
        "2020-09-01T00:00:00-05:00",
        "2020-09-03T16:33:47Z")

for f in fmts:
    print(datetime.fromisoformat(f.replace('Z', '+00:00'))) # account for Z=zulu=UTC
    
# 2020-08-28 13:42:00.298363-05:00
# 2020-09-03 16:33:47.289147+00:00
# 2020-09-01 00:00:00-05:00
# 2020-09-03 16:33:47+00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

So I combined a few of your responses and got this.
as of now it can convert also any time format.

```
def time_parser(time):
        start_period = time.split('T')[0]
        start_period_obj = datetime.strptime(start_period, "%Y-%m-%d")
        new_format = start_period_obj.strftime("%d-%b-%y")
        print('The converted date is')
        print(new_format)
        print("_______________________")
        return new_format
```